# Windows上のPythonのdatetime.strftimeで日本語を使うとエラーになる?

Tags: python, windows, python3

Windows上のPythonで下記のコードを実行するとエラーになります。
なぜでしょうか?

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
d.strftime("%y年")
```

cmd.exeでreplを起動して実行したところ、このエラーが発生しました。

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\u5e74' in position 2: Illegal byte sequence
```

Windows 10 1803 
Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

公式ドキュメントの[strftime() と strptime() の振る舞い](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)によると、PythonはCライブラリの`strftime()`関数を呼び出しています。
この呼び出しが原因で、Windows10では下記引用のUnicodeEncodeErrorになります。

> On some platforms such code points are preserved intact in the output, while on others strftime may raise [UnicodeError](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#UnicodeError) or return an empty string instead.

本家SOの[類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16034060)と、 @Kohei TAMURA さんのご回答にある[ブログ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/itasuke/20141103/p1)の内容を参考に対応方法を列挙します。

**[formatで回避する](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16035152)**

```
d.strftime('%Y{0}%m{1}%d{2}').format(*'年月日')
```

**[localeを設定する](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/itasuke/20141103/p1)**

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
# Shift-JIS範囲内のコードのみ使用可能
d.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日')
```

**[エンコードしてデコードする](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49791321)**

```
d.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日'.encode('unicode-escape').decode()).encode().decode("unicode-escape")
```

**[strftimeを自作する](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036865)**

リンク先を参照してください。

Answer (score 0):

同じエラーについて話題にしているブログがありました。未解決のバグかもしれませんね。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/itasuke/20141103/p1